# Call a custom model function from phtml file

Tags: magento2

I created a custom model `Create.php` in this path `\Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Subscription\Order` and a simple function inside it :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Subscription\Order;

class Create
{
    public function __construct();
    public function helloFromModel() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function in my block file `\app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Block`

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\HelloWorld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class HelloWorld extends Template
{
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Vendor\HelloWorld\Model\Subscription\Order\CreateFactory $orderFactory
        ) {

        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function helloFromBlock() {
        $model =  $this->_orderFactory->create();
        return $model->helloFromModel();
    }
}
```

And I expect to have a `Hello` in the phtml file :
`<h1><?php $this->helloFromBlock(); ?></h1>`

However, I have nothing printed. What wrong am I doing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to echo a returned value: `<?php echo $this->helloFromBlock(); ?>`

Comment: How I did not see this ?! Thank you so much  !

Comment: It happens to all of us, you'd gone code blind.